# Grub 2 os prober for windows 8

Tags: fedora, windows, grub2

I'm trying to dual boot with fedora 20 and windows 8.
I install first windows and then fedora. And grub detects windows automatically.

So the default `\etc\grub.d\30_os-prober` for windows is this:

```
case ${BOOT} in chain)

onstr="$(gettext_printf "(on %s)" "${DEVICE}")"
cat << EOF
  menuentry '$(echo "${LONGNAME} $onstr" | grub_quote)' --class windows --class os \$menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-$(grub_get_device_id "${DEVICE}")' {
EOF
  save_default_entry | grub_add_tab
  prepare_grub_to_access_device ${DEVICE} | grub_add_tab

  case ${LONGNAME} in
    Windows\ Vista*|Windows\ 7*|Windows\ Server\ 2008*)
    ;;
    *)
    cat << EOF
      drivemap -s (hd0) \${root}
    EOF
    ;;
  esac

  cat <<EOF
  chainloader +1
}
```

This creates this `menuentry` which doesn't boot windows:

**What I've tried**

I created in my `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` manually a `menuentry` which works fine

```
menuentry "Windows" {
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod fat
  insmod search_fs_uuid
  insmod chain
  search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root your_UUID
  chainloader (${root})/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

So I try to adapt this for the `\etc\grub.d\30_os-prober` and add replace the last part with this:

```
cat <<EOF
  search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root $(grub_get_device_id "${DEVICE}")
  chainloader (${root})/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
EOF
```

but this creates:

```
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager' {
      chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
      boot
}
```

Which doesn't work.

**My question**

How should I change 30_os-prober so that it creates a working grub menuentry?

Comment: I don't know a ton about grub, but if I were you I would try changing `Windows\ Vista*|Windows\ 7*|Windows\ Server\ 2008*)` to `Windows\ Vista*|Windows\ 7*|Windows\ Server\ 2008*|Windows\ 8*)`.

Comment: Consider using [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) as your bootloader. For more information on how it stacks up to grub, look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/760971/256314)

Answer (score 0):

I am not that well versed with the Fedora and its Grub2. But i will share a solution i adopted in my dual-boot system with Ubuntu and Windows XP Professional
Edit grub.cfg with vim or any other editor

```
vim /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

To:

```
 121 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
    122 menuentry "Microsoft Windows XP Professional (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
    123     insmod part_msdos
    124     insmod ntfs
    125     set root='(/dev/sda,msdos1)'
    126     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root AC60CA8160CA522E
    127     drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    128     chainloader +1
    129 }
```

as the Ubuntu grub default adds this Windows as the last entry. I just added this entry in front of all other menu entries.

Comment: your solution look like what I do at the moment in 30_custom, but thank you anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

menuentry "WINDOWS"{
set root='(hd0,msdos1)' 
chainloader +1
}

Change the partition number , where your windows is installed.
hd0 :- means first disk 
msdos1 :- means first partition.

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` segment quoted in the OP generates a GRUB entry for Windows *that boots in legacy BIOS-style*.

But the working custom entry in the OP indicates the system uses UEFI-style. That means `os-prober` should be detecting Windows as a generic UEFI operating system. In other words, if you run `os-prober` as root, the result should be of the form

```
/dev/<ESP partition>@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
```

which should trigger the `efi)` case in the `30_os-prober` script, not the `chain)` case. The resulting GRUB menu entry should be similar to:

```
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on <ESP device>)' --class windows --class os 
$menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-<ESP UUID>' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <ESP UUID>
        chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Given that the ESP is usually a FAT32 partition, the `<ESP UUID>` is usually just the FAT32 filesystem Volume Serial Number, of the form `XXXX-XXXX` instead of a real UUID.

Of course, given that the question is now almost 10 years old, it is possible that GRUB's `30_os-prober` script did not include the `efi)` case yet at that time.